# Value of type '[Double]?' has no member 'append'

Tags: arrays, swift, append, double

I have the following problem:

> Value of type '[Double]?' has no member 'append'

My code:

```
var values : [Double]?

if (value.string == nil) {
    values = (dataChart[key])!
    values.append(Double.nan)
    dataChart[key] = values
} else {
    values = dataChart[key]!
    values.append(Double(value.int!))
    dataChart[key] = values
}
```

Comment: `[Double]?` doesn't have `.append`, `[Double]` has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) to append a value to an optional array. And avoid force unwrapping. Since `values` array is declared as an optional, you don't need to force unwrap `dataChart[key]!`. Just use `dataChart[key]`

```
if value.string == nil {
    values = dataChart[key]
    values?.append(Double.nan)
    dataChart[key] = values
} else {
    values = dataChart[key]
    if let intValue = value.int {
        values?.append(Double(intValue))
    }
    dataChart[key] = values
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to append with a for

and you have to save it in an array

```
var resultArray: [RegisterObject] = []
```

example:

```
for register in results {

                let obj = RegisterObject()

                obj.celNumber = register.celNumber
                obj.dv = register.dv
                obj.gId = register.gId

                resultArray.append(obj)
            }
```